# Unit Tests - can / should I use setUp and tearDown, when my instantiation varies?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, phpunit

Say I have a class that uses parameters in constructor, as such:

```
$var = new MyClass(1, 2, 3);
```

and my various tests depend on the parameters being passed to the class.

I have noticed that PHPUnit has setUp() and tearDown() methods, which can be used to instantiate a class, usually when constructor has no parameters, before execution of each test.

Is there a way to use `setUp` and `tearDown` methods in my test harness for such classes as in my example, or do I just instead instnatiate my classes individually in each test, as I have been doing?

I am asking this question more so to check that I have not missed anything on how to use `setUp` and `tearDown` properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with inf3rno's answer: you should not use setUp if the constructor needs parameters.

Maybe you can get advantage of another feature: dataProviders. They allow you to define multiple data sets for the same test:

```
public function sumExamples()
{
    return array(
       array(1, 2, 3),
       array(1, -1, 0),
       array(-1, -2, -3)
    );
}

/**
 * @dataProvider sumExamples
 */
public function testSum($a, $b, $expected_result)
{
    $instance = new Sum(1, 2);
    $this->assertEquals($expected_result, $sum->getValue());
}
```

[PHPUnit docs on this](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers)

This technique is useful only when the assertions are the same for all the data sets, of course.

Finally, if the constructor parameters are mandatory for the object to work, I'd keep them where they are. Getting rid of them just so you can instantiate the object at setUp is not correct IMO.

Comment: yepp, data sets are fine as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> and my various tests depend on the parameters being passed to the
>   class.

If the test is depending on the constructor parameters, you cannot use setUp to create the instances... Setup is for repetitive things... Try to avoid constructor injection if possible, so you can use something like this:

```
protected $instance;
public function setUp(){
    $this->instance = new MyClass();
}

public function testSomething(){
    $this->instance->setParams(1,2,3);
    //...
    $this->assertEquals(...);
}

public function testSomethingElse(){
    $this->instance->setFirstParam(1);
    $this->instance->setSecondParam(2);
    $this->instance->setThirdParam(3);
    //...
    $this->assertEquals(...);
}
```

Ofc. this depends on what your Class does...

Comment: thanks ... that kind of sets me on the path of .. do I want to avoid constructor injection or do I want to use it.  That's a deeper topic.  I thought about it for a while and I wanted to avoid situations where setters were not properly called, so I put parameters into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The two methods `setUp` and `tearDown` are mostly by convention. You can make use of them if you need to, but you must not.

E.g. it can be perfectly fine that you have a private helper method that helps you to create instances of the subject under test. You could also use `setUp` to create a factory for those. Do what helps you keeping the code of the tests small and dead simple.

As you have not shared any of your test-code, I can not give a more specific suggestion.

Read on: [xUnit (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit) and [Implicit Setup (xUnit Pattern)](http://xunitpatterns.com/Implicit%20Setup.html).